# Let $A⊆B⊆\mathbb{R}$, and $f:B→\mathbb{R},\ g:\ g(x)=f(x)$ for $x∈A$,give an example that $g$ is continuous at $c∈A$, $f$ is not continuous at $c$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A⊆B⊆\mathbb{R}$, and $f:B→\mathbb{R},\ g:\ g(x)=f(x)$ for $x∈A$,give an example that if $g$ is continuous at $c∈A$, it need not follow that $f$ is continuous at $c$

Does Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you think of something like that:

$A=\{0\}\subset B=\Bbb R$, and $g(0)=0$ and $f(x)=[x]$ (entire part) on $B$.

Comment: I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $A=(0,1)$ and $g(x)=0.$ Can you define a function $$f:B=[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$$ that is not continuous at $x=0?$ What could be $f(0)?$

Comment: I got it, thanks